# Node.js require-function parent object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

I mean if I want to do something in browser, such as call eval, I can do this:

```
window['eval']();
```

As in "calling eval with string".

But in Node there is no window. There is `global`, but that does not have require in it.

What contains require in node, so that I can do:

`???['require']();`

I tried `this[require]` in global scope and `global['require']` and I also tried finding the require function parent with `require.prototype`and `require.constructor` but without luck.

Edit:

`require` does indeed exist *somewhere*, because by just writing `require('vm')` for example, it works.

The [Node.js source](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/node.js) contains `NativeModule.require` and `nativeModule` references, but `NativeModule` is not defined when I try to use it.

Comment: I'm also baffled... From the docs (https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_require): `To require modules. See the Modules section. require isn't actually a global but rather local to each module.`

Comment: `window['eval']` is a reference to the `eval` function, but because it's in window, you can just use `eval` instead. `require` function in nodejs is injected, so you can just use it as `require`, no need for `prefix.require`. Why would you ever want to use `require` as a dynamic function? Post what exactly you want :)

Comment: @AndreyPopov Maybe I want to bypass something that checks code for "require" words. So for eval it would work like `var e = 'ev'; var a = 'al'; window[e+a](code)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`module['require']` worked for me in the end. I am using Node v0.10.35 in case that matters.

Two other globals to look the require function for could be `global['require']` or perhaps even `process['require']`?

Comment: `process.require` is undefined for me (Node 4).

Answer (score 1):

`global['require']` exists in Node 0.10+, so you have made a mistake or you are using some very ancient version of Node.

Comment: I had to use `module['require']`. I am running Node.js v0.10.35. But it works now :)

Comment: Interesting - `module.require === global.require // false`